# "Cassinian Circular " arc

Tags: analytic-geometry

If a constant angle $\gamma$ is subtended between straight lines drawn from two fixed foci then loci are Circular Arcs. And if the product of these line segment $d_1d_2$ is a constant, then loci are Cassinian Ovals.

What are the loci if product $ (\sqrt{d_1d_2} \cos\frac{ \gamma }{2} )$ is constant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
$$k = \sqrt{d_1d_2}\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}\quad\to\quad k^2 = d_1 d_2\cos^2\frac{\gamma}{2} = d_1 d_2\cdot\frac12(1+\cos\gamma) \tag{1}$$
so that, with a soon-to-be-convenient extra factor of $2$,
$$4k^2 = 2d_1d_2(1+\cos\gamma) \tag{2}$$
Writing $2d$ for the distance between the foci, the Law of Cosines tells us
$$(2d)^2 = d_1^2+d_2^2-2d_1d_2\cos\gamma \tag{3}$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$,
$$4d^2 + 4 k^2 = d_1^2 + d_2^2 + 2 d_1 d_2 = ( d_1+d_2)^2 \tag{4}$$
and we deduce
$$d_1+d_2= 2 \sqrt{d^2+k^2} \tag{5}$$

The locus is (an arc of) an ellipse. $\square$

Comment: With $ d_1+ d_2=2 a,d=c, k=b $ we have $ a^2= b^2+c^2.$